# Comment « emprunt » a-t-il evolué pour signifier « prêt » (ainsi qu'une volte-face) ?

Tags: étymologie

<sub>Je commence par clarifier que mon usage de « emprunter » réfère au débiteur, et « prêter » au créditeur.

1. Donc, au début, le créancier donne de l'argent au débiteur.

2. À la fin, le créancier devrait recevoir de l'argent du débiteur.</sub>

« prêter » n'a pas changé sémantiquement; son étymon latin [praestō](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/praesto#Verbe_2) veut dire «  Prêter, fournir ».

Par contre, « emprunt » s'est transformé de 1 en 2 (et 2 est décrit par son <sup>■</sup>'Relational Antonym'), en tant qu'une volte-face.
À savoir, son étymon latin [promutuor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/promutuor#Latin) ne se réfère à que 2 ci-dessus et veut dire 'to lend beforehand', mais actuellement «  emprunt » inclut 2 aussi.

<sub><sup>■</sup>Voir p 157, *An Introduction to Language* (10 ed, 2014) by V Fromkin, R Rodman, N Hyams.

Le terme de Sémantique (une branche de la Linguistique) <sup>■</sup>'[Relational Antonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28semantics%29#Relational_antonyms)' ou '[Relational Opposite](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zq9uCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA157&ots=eDPabBPgAy&dq=%22Relational%20opposites%22%20fromkin&pg=PA157#v=onepage&q=%22Relational%20opposites%22%20fromkin&f=false)' applique à « emprunter » et « prêter ».</sub>

Comment: Dans le Robert, *emprunt* n'a que le 1er sens lorsqu'il concerne l'argent. Un créancier peut lui-même emprunter à une personne tierce, mais il n'a pas de relation d'emprunt avec son débiteur (il ne peut dire que "M.X m'a emprunté de l'argent, ma voiture..."[Il parle du prêt qu'il lui à accordé]) -- Est-il possible d'avoir le ou les paragraphes du 'Relational Opposite' concernant ces deux termes ?

Comment: @cl-r Comme toujours, je vous remercie de votre commentaire. J'ai ajouté deux liens, duquels un est Google Books; informez-moi s'il a limité les pages.

Comment: Je n'ai pas trouvé les mots *emprunter* et *prêter* sur les pages publiées sur le second lien cité, mais sur la page française correspondant au premier lien, au § **Conversif** : "On appelle conversifs (ou réciproques) les couples comme 'acheter'|||_d 'vendre' , 'prêter' |||_d 'emprunter' ..." mais pas de trace du mot *emprunt* lié à un vendeur.

Comment: @cl-r Je suis désolé de vous embrouiller. C'était moi, et non pas les livres, qui a appliqué ce terme linguistique à 'emprunter' et 'prêter', car je voudrais faire attention à la relation entre ces deux substantifs.

Comment: emprunt ne signifie pas prêt, et n'a pas évolué dans ce sens. Les 2 mots sont d'origines différentes (indiquées), ont un sens réciproque. La question n'est simplement pas fondée.

Answer (score 1):

La façon qu'ont les linguistes d'aborder les langues par l'abstraction, par la modélisation et les jargons associés est  étrangère à la très grande majorité des francophones.

Dans le langage courant *acheter/vendre* est considéré comme une interaction, comme deux extrémités du même 'lien'.

De même pour l'amour et la haine qui sont *en opposition*, en positions inconciliables.

Dans les deux cas on ne peut-être acheteur et vendeur du même objet, on ne peut aimer et haïr la même chose (ou personne) dans le même temps... mais le temps peut faire évoluer les choses et renverser les situations.

Pour les objets qui concernent l'avoir les situations sont plus simples que pour les sentiments qui concernent l'être : ils peuvent être mélangés lorsque le sentiment évoqué n'est pas 'entier'.